# Basic C++ Dice game

Tags: c++, c++11, dice

I have a problem here, would be really nice if anyone could help me out here. Its my first time using this program so dont be to judgemental.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int throw1, throw2, throw3, throw4;
int bet1 = 100;
int bet2 = 300;
int bet3 = 500;
int bet=(bet1, bet2, bet3);
int deposit;
int account;

int main(){
    int count = 0;

    while(count < 3){

        cin>>deposit;

        while(deposit>5000 || deposit<0){                //Makes sure so that my deposit is between 0-5000
            cout<<"deposit failed"<<endl;
            cin>>deposit;

        }
        account = deposit;
        cout<<"You have deposited" <<deposit<<"Swedish Krona"<<endl;   
        cout<<"and you have this much cash on your account"<<account<<"Swedish Krona"<<endl;

        if (konto>499){                 //Makes sure so that i have the money to bet, and if i dont have the money, i can just put in more 
            cout<<"please place your bet"<<endl;
            cout<<"bet1=100, bet2=300, bet3=500"<<endl;
            cin>>bet1;
            cin>>bet2;
            cin>>bet3;
            account = (deposit - bet);
            cout<<"you have this much cash on your account"<<account<<"Swedish Krona"<<endl;
        }
        else if(account>299){
            cout<<"please place your bet"<<endl;
            cout<<"bet1=100, bet=300"<<endl;     
            cin>>bet1;
            cin>>bet2;
            account =(deposit - bet);
            cout<<"you have this much cash on your account"<<account<<"Swedish Krona"<<endl;
        }
        else if(account>99){
            cout<<"please place your bet"<<endl;
            cout<<"bet1=100"<<endl;
            cin>>bet1;
            cout<<"you have placed your bet"<<bet<<"Swedish Krona"<<endl;
        }

        while (account<100 || deposit>5000){
            cout<<"insufficient funds"<<endl;
            cin>>deposit;
            account=deposit;
        }

        {
            cout<<"Throw dice"<<endl;
            srand(time(0)); 
            Throw1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
            Throw2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
            Throw3 = rand() % 6 + 1;
            Throw4 = rand() % 6 + 1;
            cout<<"You rolled"<<Throw1<<endl;
            cout<<"You rolled"<<Throw2<<endl;
            cout<<"Computer rolled"<<Throw3<<endl;
            cout<<"Computer rolled"<<Throw4<<endl;
        }
    }
    count++;

    system ("pause");
}
```

So the thing here is that, for some reason i always bet 500, even though type in bet1 or bet2, and i have no clue how to fix that problem. And then my loop function `(int count 0;  while(count < 3)count++)` it starts to loop endlessly without me pressing anything, even though i use the same loop function in simple coding like just typing some cout<< things it works fine, but when i use it in this code, it goes to drain, do anyone know why this is happening, would appreciate if anyone could answer, thanks in advanced.

Comment: It would be helpful if you renamed your variables into English and also translated comments

Comment: Call srand() only 1 time in the execution of your program. Never ever put it in a loop.

Comment: It's impossible to guess what you mean by `int bet=(bet1, bet2, bet3)`. I would recommend you to review the basics about variables and assignment again.

Comment: I would recommend you debug into your program and step through each part, so that you get a better understanding of why each part is not doing what you think it is. As it stands, this has several problems with it and is a little too broad for SO.

Answer (score 9):

```
int bet1 = 100;
int bet2 = 300;
int bet3 = 500;
int bet=(bet1, bet2, bet3)
```

The last line will be evaluated like this: 100, 300, 500. Result of comma separated list of expression will be last value, which is 500. So your bet variable will be always set to 500.

Answer (score 5):

What you state in your comment below the code, `(int count 0; while(count < 3)count++)`looks like some weird mixture of `for` and `while` loop. Please check again your C++ textbook/online tutorials about how to write a correct loop.

In the code you show, in your `while` loop, you don't modify the `count` variable - therefore it will loop forever if count is < 3 before the loop. The indentation of your code is really misleading. I have taken the liberty of reformatting your code - and now you should see that the `count++` statement actually is outside of your main `while` loop!

When you want to do something for a fixed number of times, it's recommendable to use a `for` loop, it makes it harder to forget the increment!

Comment: Yeah, i saw that aswell, so changed it, and it dosent go on rampage now, and it loops the amount that i want it to loop, but it dosent let me redo my betting, i can just press something and it does it automatically, bet when i use this code on something random i do it works fine

Comment: show us the program output along with your input, and what you actually expect to happen, then somebody may be able to help you

Answer (score 3):

You increase `count` *outside* the loop, so it will *always* be zero. Either move it inside the loop (proper indentation is key!) or maybe use a `for` loop instead:

```
for (count = 0; count < 3; ++count) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some advice,

- place your prompt for deposit (insattning) into a function
- place your prompt for bet into a function
- check for sufficient money before prompting for bet
- get input into a string, then validate input (not done below, yet)
- check that bet is valid (=100,=300,=500, bet<=konto)

Here are these convenience functions,

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int kast1, kast2, kast3, kast4;
int bet1 = 100;
int bet2 = 300;
int bet3 = 500;
int bet=0; //assignment didn't make sense
int insattning=0;
int konto=0;

//deposit
int get_insattning()
{
    int good = 0;
    while( !good )
    {
        cout<<"deposit"<<endl; //prompt for deposit
        cin>>insattning;
        if(insattning>5000 || insattning<0)//Makes sure so that my deposit is between 0-5000
        {
            cout<<"insattning fel, var vänlig och gör rätt denna gången"<<endl;
        }
        else good = 1;
    }
    cout<<"du har nu satt in" <<insattning<<"kr"<<endl;
    return insattning;
}
```

It isn't clear to me whether you want 1 bet of 100,300,or 500, or 3 bets.  This does the first,

```
//bet
int get_bet()
{
    int good = 0;
    int bet;
    std::string validbets = "";
    if(konto<100){ cout<<"you need more money"; return 0; }
    while( !good )
    {
        cout<<"var vänlig och placera ditt bet"<<endl;
        if(konto>=100){ validbets = "bet1=100"; }
        if(konto>=300){ validbets += ", bet=300"; }
        if(konto>=500){ validbets += ", bet=500"; }
        cout<<validbets<<endl;
        cin>>bet;
        if( bet >= konto ) {
            cout<<"you don't have enough money"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        if (bet==500){                 //Makes sure so that i have the money to bet, and if i dont have the money, i can just put in more 
            cout<<"du har så här mycket på kontot nu "<<konto<<" kr"<<endl;
            good = 1;
        }
        else if(bet==300){
            cout<<"du har så mycket på kontot nu "<<konto<<" kr"<<endl;
            good = 1;
        }
        else if(bet==100){
            cout<<"du har nu bettat "<<bet<<" kr"<<endl;
            good = 1;
        }
        else {
            cout<<"you must place valid bet"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return bet;
}
```

Now your main game play is cleaner/easier to read.  I don't know what the win conditions are or the payout, and since your prompts are not english, I cannot read them to tell what to do next,

```
int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int bet;
    srand(time(0));
    for( count=0; (count < 3); count++)
    {
        konto = get_insattning();
        if (konto<100)
        {
            cout<<"du har inte nog med pengar, vänligen sätt in pengar"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        cout<<"och du har så här mycket i ditt konto "<<konto<<" kr"<<endl;
        bet = get_bet();
        //when you bet, reduce konto by bet
        konto = (konto - bet);
        {
            cout<<"slå tärningar"<<endl;
            kast1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
            kast2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
            kast3 = rand() % 6 + 1;
            kast4 = rand() % 6 + 1;
            cout<<"Du fick"<<kast1<<endl;
            cout<<"du fick"<<kast2<<endl;
            cout<<"datorn fick"<<kast3<<endl;
            cout<<"datorn fick"<<kast4<<endl;
        }
```

You need to write code for determining whether you won or lost, and then add to konto when you win,

```
        //did you win or lose?
        //win?  add money to konto
        //lose?  you have already deducted from konto
    }
    system ("pause");
}
```

These suggestions should help you fix your program.

Comment: thanks alot for the help, just one problem that occurs, the loop goes endlessly

Comment: Look at your termination conditions on each loop.  You might consider (as I said) replacing the prompt input with allowing a "quit" or "exit" entry.  Or exit when input <0?  Oh, and you might check for EOF (end of file) on cin.